# How to remove T from time format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, jinja2

How to remove T from time format  `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S` in python?

Am using it in my html as

```
<b>Start:{{ start.date_start  }}<br/>
```

Comment: Is this Jinja2 or Django templating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@register.filter
def isotime(datestring):
    datestring = str(datestring)
    return datestring.replace("T"," ")
```

Answer (score 3):

Manually format the datetime, don't rely on the default `str()` formatting. You can use [`datetime.datetime.isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) for example, passing in a space as the separator:

```
<b>Start:{{ start.date_start.isoformat(' ')  }}<br/>
```

or you can use [`datetime.datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) to control formatting more finely:

```
<b>Start:{{ start.date_start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  }}<br/>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for the Answer. It is fruitful but I tried template tag function instead. like: 

@register.filter
def isotime(datestring):
    datestring = str(datestring)
    return datestring.replace("T"," ")

Comment: So why not use `dateobj.isoformat(' ')` instead of `str(dateobj).repace()`?

Comment: @GentleJoseph note: `str(datetime)` does *not* contain `T`. `datetime.__str__` is *documented* to return `d.isoformat(' ')` i.e., it would be a bug if there were `T` in the result. So the question is: what type does `start.date_start` have? Is it a string (then `.replace()` is tolerable, though `strptime().strftime()` (reformat) is better) or is it some custom date class? (then use the explicit formatting methods such as `.strftime()`).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: good point, which means that `start.date_start` must be a string *already*.